# mysql load file using pipe

Tags: python, mysql

How do I use pipe to mysql load data infile using python? The below doesn't seem to be working. Local infile expect file and so not sure if its failing because of that.

```
cat = Popen(["cat /Users/test/filename.out"], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=-1, shell=True)
load = """load data local infile - into table %s fields terminated by '|' lines terminated by '\\n';""" % (tablename)

with conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    for line in cat.stdout:
        cursor.execute(load.stdin.write(line))
cat.stdout.close()
cat.wait()
load.stdin.close()
load.wait()
```

Comment: Why are you using `cat`?  Why are you using a shell?

Comment: the `cat` is just for representation here. I've a data stream instead of `cat` in the above example.